# Set default target language version in visual(C# 2015) with config file

Tags: c#, configuration, acumatica

I have a trouble with target language in visual. I had install VS2015 that have C# language version 6.0.

And problem is I can't build it in version 6.0 because I just work with Website. It's not same with C# project. I use Acumatica ERP so it's just have 1 Site for all file(Csharp code in there too)

My Framework need C# 6.0 or higher to build.

I had try use nuget package install but I can't install new Compiler from there too. And I want config it by some file text(Look like web.config)

If you have any ideas, please help me :(

Comment: "And problem is I can't build it in version 6.0 because I just work with Website. It's not same with C# project. I use Acumatica ERP so it's just have 1 Site for all file(Csharp code in there too)" I don´t get what you mean by this.

Comment: This is something that the product owner needs to do.  They need to switch from System.CodeDom to Roslyn.  All you can do is let them know that this is important to you.

Comment: Yes, I need switch from System.CodeDom.

Comment: Did you create a project in visual studio with a reference to the Acumatica site? Are you building the Acumatica site? (you should exclude the site from being built under the solution - Configuration Manager). Can you post the full error message you are getting? What version of Acumatica?

Comment: Acumatica version 6.1 @Brendan

Answer (score 0):

You can fairly easy customize your build by modifying the VS-project-file which is nothing but an xml. Simply define a `PropertyGroup` upon your condition and set the `LangVersion`, e.g. to either `ISO-1` or `ISO-2` depending on your target-platform.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <LangVersion>ISO-1</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
    <LangVersion>ISO-2</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try with your help

Comment: I'm thinking about add your code to my web.config. Will it work?. I don't know where to place your code

Comment: As already mentioned you have to put it into the csproj-file. However you need some other condition to make the switch,l the target-plattform was just an example.

Comment: Oh man... My project doesn't have csprojet.
I work in website project. It's just have csharp file...